# Android simple_list_item_single_choice Blank When using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, list, simplecursoradapter

I can't figure this one out for the life of me.  I am querying a database for a list, and passing that list to an AlertDialog to get user input.  I am using a simple_spinner_item currently, and the data displays just fine.  However, the rows are too narrow when using this method, and I would like to change the width.  I experimented with a couple of different methods:

1. Changing the:

   ```
   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
   ```

To a list based layout like:

```
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice
```

This would be perfect, but the list is blank!  The items show up when I click on them individually.  So that's not working.

1. I have also tried using a custom XML file with the definition of a Textview, and setting up the drop down resource like this (file: db_view_row.xml):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <TextView android:text=""
   android:id="@+id/tvDBViewRow"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#FF0000" />  
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

and referencing it here:

```
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.db_view_row}; 
    adapterDenomination.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.db_view_row);
```

That doesn't work either (blank rows), although when I used a straight spinner originally it did (which I cannot use because the first item is automatically selected).

Here is the original code snippet:

```
            String[] from = new String[] {"denomination_desc" };                
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }; 

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            SimpleCursorAdapter adapterDenomination = new SimpleCursorAdapter(CoinsScreen.this, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor, from, to  ); 



             new AlertDialog.Builder(CoinsScreen.this) 
              .setTitle("Select Denomination") 
              .setAdapter(adapterDenomination, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
              { 

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                { 
                       (...)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The custom XML file solution should have worked, but probably it was due to pointing to an erroneous id.

You had:

```
int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.db_view_row}; 
adapterDenomination.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.db_view_row);
```

Probably it should have been:

```
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvDBViewRow }; 
adapterDenomination.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.db_view_row);
```

Also, if you can't still get it to work, try to add the following lines to your custom TextView:

```
style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargeInverse"
```

Cheers!

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick help! but unfortunately, it still doesn't work.  I made a mistake in the original post, I did have this: int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvDBViewRow };, I messed up in the editor and pasted a comment.... I tried adding the style attribute to the XML.  The only way I can get it to work is to use int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 }; and simple_spinner _item, which, unfortunatly will not work for this application.  Everything else i have tried either results in a blank row, or a row that highlights the contents when clicked

Comment: simple_dropdown_item_1line seems to work with int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 }; but it's ugly and actually too big.  Still can't seem to find the right combination to get that custom XML textview to work....

Comment: Hmm... strange. I had a similar problem, which I solved by using a default ArrayAdapter with a custom layout ( final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.dropdown_item, R.id.txt_spinner); ) and setting the TextView fields like the ones I posted above plus setting the color to black.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunatly it appears (since I have to use a cursor), that I will be limited to something like the simple_dropdown_item_1line and no customization.  After working for many years in Microsoft (MFC, .NET, etc...), I am really finding Android to be difficult....

Comment: Solved it!  The issue was using setDropDownViewResource on a layout that doesn't support it.  On some of the types, I need to use SetViewResource, and it's good to go.  Thanks jcxavier for getting the thought juices flowing!

Comment: Happy I was able to help a little :)